# List<E> Implementations

Tags: java, list

I'm creating a simple Game of War with cards for my Data Structures class.

I currently have a method as follows:

```
Play Turn(List<Card> player1, List<Card> player2){
    return null;
}
```

The above method (which I understand is incomplete currently) is suppose to accept any subinterface of the List interface(i.e. Stack, ArrayList, LinkedList, etc.).

The Stack uses pop() to return/remove the top of the Stack, and something like an ArrayList or LinkedList I can use the get() method to return the first element and then the remove() method to remove that element.

So is there a way that I can do this in a generic way, or do I have to create a method tailored to each version of List I allow to be used?

Comment: `Stack`, `ArrayList`, ..., all implement the `List` interface's methods (like `get`, `remove`, ...), so you could just use those for everything... why use the specific `Stack` methods (like `pop`) when you don't have to?

Comment: You do not need separate implementations if you restrict your implementations to List methods.  If you imagine that you need to know the underlying type, think again.

Comment: This answers my question. I was under the impression that although I was using the 'Stack' under the 'List' interface, that I would have to use the methods such as 'pop' compared to using methods such as 'get' and 'remove'.

Comment: the whole point of accepting an interface is that you don't need to worry about the actual implementation. use the `List` methods, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Please learn and follow the Java coding standards ([Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) or [Sun/Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)).  Your code is less understandable without them.

Your method should look like this:

```
Play turn(List<Card> player1, List<Card> player2) {
    return null;
}
```

The meaning is clear: You can pass any reference to an `Object` on the heap that implements the `List` interface.  It means that your implementation should only call methods in the `List` interface.  You should not be concerned with the concrete implementation of the reference you're given.

I don't understand where `Stack` plays in this interface.  A `Stack` might be implemented using a `List`, but its methods (push, pop, peek) are not part of the `List` interface.  They'll be off limits to the parameters in your interface.

If you think your methods needs a `Stack<Turn>` for each player, then you should not have a `List` as parameter.

Comment: Should there be a space between `)` and `{`? (I'm not entirely sure what the Java coding standards are, as I'm mainly a C# guy, but the example's I've seen follow the first format....)

Comment: I'm referring to the method name  - it should be turn, not Turn.  I would have a space between the two.  You put the curly brace in the right spot: at the end of the method declaration, not on the next line.

Comment: I'm still learning all the standards as I'm only a second year student, so I do apologize for the mistakes I made.

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria yes there should be a space there.

Answer (score 0):

Any class that implements the `List` interface will make a series of promises about what happens when the `List` methods are called.  They may fulfil the promises in a different way, but the promises will be met across all implementations.

For example, a call to `get(0)` on any implementation of `List` will return the first item in the list.  This will be true no matter whether you are using an `ArrayList`, a `LinkedList`, a `Stack`, or a `JoesCustomList`.  There is therefore no need to tailor your method for different types of list.

Answer (score 0):

To the contrary:unless you have really good reasons you absolutely want to avoid any kind of **downcast**! So any kind of instanceof-check and downcast to a concrete implementation of the List interface is something that you do not want to have in your code!

Meaning: one of the major advantages of these interfaces is the fact that they already contain the methods you will need to call.

In other words: one of the key values of such interfaces is the fact that the interface alone provides those methods one needs to get the job done. They provide a powerful **abstraction** that allows your code to be completely agnostic to the question "how is that interface actually implemented!"